# Where can i see Python terminal outputs

Tags: python, azure, terminal, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed Python web app on azure web app service that prints outputs in to terminal. Where I can see that without attaching a debugger. My app is using this startup command.

```
python3.10 -m aiohttp.web -H 0.0.0.0 -P 8000 app:init_func
```

I just want to see the outputs of that.

Comment: Are you just printing? Using the logging library? You should post `app:init_func`

Comment: the app is printing to the console itself. I am not printing anything manually. It's basically the langchain output that I wanna see.

Comment: By langchain, Are you using a streamlit app? or normal python web app with langchain used?

Comment: @SiddheshDesai Just a Python web app that routes answers to Teams Bot.

Comment: @Axen_Rangs You can check the output of that command in `App Service=>Monitoring=>Log Stream`.

Comment: @PravallikaKV Log Stream doesn't show terminal output for me.It just says ready to serve requests.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your terminal output & Log stream?

Comment: @Axen_Rangs You have to enable [Application Logging](https://i.imgur.com/AYxOCQW.png) in `App Service=>App Service Logs`. Then browse the application URL, you'll be able to see the *output of your command* in **Log Stream**

Answer (score 1):

Posting my comments as answer

You can use the  **Log stream**  feature in the Azure portal to see the outputs of your application.  Log stream shows live `console logs and traces` of the web application.

- Before checking the ***Logs*** in **Log stream**, `Application Logging` should be enabled.
- Open your web app in `Azure =>App Services`.
- In the left pane of your app, navigate to  **Monitoring**  section and select  **App Service Logs** and Set `Application Logging` to File System and its level to Information as shown below:

[image]

**Startup command:**

[image]

- Run your application URL `<https://<web_app_name>.azurewebsites.net>` .
- Check the output logs in `Monitoring=>LogStream`  section, you will be able to see the output of the startup command:

[image]